# How to get to configure Octave on mac to get to previous command

Tags: macos, octave, command-prompt

I am new to Octave and sometimes due to typo or for rerunning a command, I need to get to previously entered command. I read through the GNUwiki and found Control-p should work didn't work for me. Looked for other posts in stackovefrflow too.

As a comparison, in mac Terminal app I could use up and down arrow to get to previous/next commands.

Comment: Are you using the command-line interface, the default GUI, or some other GUI?

Comment: I am using default command line GUI provided by Octave

Comment: It's the CLI-GUI!

Answer (score 0):

Up arrow to go through your command history should work in Octave on Mac in both the Command Line Interface and the GUI.

If it's not working, you may need to edit your `~/.inputrc` file to bind up-arrow to previous-command. Or your terminal settings may be messed up.

If you're still having trouble, you may need support from the Octave developers, in which case you should post a bug report on [the GNU Octave Savannah bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=browse&set=open&group=octave).